# How to add project to my portfolio on Behance?

Tags: behance-api

I want to add projects on Behance. But I am not able to add any projects. I dont understand which format I supposed to add.

I am new to stack-overflow. Please help me to these problem. If i am not clear my question please post comments , i will edit my question. And I am sorry,  I am not able to add any screenshot,because I need reputation add images.

I really need your help.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Projects tab. In the left hand column, you'll notice that “Your Behance Projects” are listed at the top. Drag whichever project you’d like to add to ProSite down into the “Gallery” section.

[Behance help](https://help.behance.net/hc/en-us/articles/204486234-ProSite-How-can-I-add-remove-projects-from-my-Behance-Portfolio-to-my-ProSite-)

[image]

Comment: I did it several times but its not added. When i added html website then ,showed me "please fix your extension".  I really don't understand. But Thank you for help,

Comment: check your  Behance App Client ID and Secret in Configuration. again

Comment: I am trying last 7 days but same problem.and right now i am not able to give screenshot because of stack-overflow rules. And I am here.